# Prove that if $\mathcal{F}'$ is normal and $\sup_{f ∈ \mathcal{F}} \{ |f(z_0)| \} < +∞$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is normal

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

## The question

Let $Ω$ be a domain in $ℂ$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of holomorphic functions at $Ω$, and let $\mathcal{F}' = \left\{ f':\ f∈\mathcal{F} \right\}$ be the family of derivatives of $\mathcal{F}$.

1. Show that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family, then $\mathcal{F}'$ is also normal.
2. Give an example to show that the reciprocal is incorrect.
3. Prove that if $\mathcal{F}'$ is normal and for some $z_0 ∈ Ω$ we have $\sup_{f ∈ \mathcal{F}} \{ |f(z_0)| \} < +∞$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is normal.

---

## What I can't solve

I've been able to solve 1. (as a Weierstrass consequence) and 2.

But I don't know how to even try 3.

Any help?

Comment: This question is similar http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567637/family-of-normal-derivatives-does-not-imply-family-is-normal and the answers apply for this question as well. Should this be closed as a duplicate? – I am reluctant to copy my answer.

Comment: @MartinR I've read your answer and it definitely solves my problem. So for me it's ok to mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've reached [using the comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399886/partial-converse-to-mathcalf-normal-implies-mathcalf-normal?rq=1):

$$ f(z) = f(z_0) + \int_γ f'(w)\ dw, $$

where $γ$ is a path that connects $z_0$ and $z$. By Paul-Montel we know that $\mathcal{F}'$ is uniformly bounded over compacts of $Ω$, so if we take a compact such that $γ ⊂ K⊂Ω$, we can find a bound for the integral:

$$ |f(z)| ≤ |f(z_0)| +  \int_γ \left|\ f'(w) \right|\ dw ≤ |f(z_0)| + M_K · \text{arc-length}(γ), $$

where $M_K$ is the bound for every $f'$ at $K$.

Then we have that every $f \in \mathcal{F}$ is uniformly bounded, and using Paul-Montel again we get that $\mathcal{F}$ is normal.

Comment: The problem here is to get a bound for the arc length.

Comment: @MartinR you got me there. But if $Ω$ is bounded then there is no problem, no?

Comment: Even if the domain is bounded, it is not obvious (to me), as the connecting path must be inside the domain (which for example could look like an infinite spiral).

Comment: @MartinR totally missed that one. I'm checking out your answer, thanks.